# What/how many different cities are officially supported by Dresden Files?

Tags: dresden-files

Obviously the main setting is from the books, but that's just one city. Are there any other cities or towns that have official support? If not, where's a good place to find fan-made settings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Baltimore is the most fully realized setting,

The Dresden Files RPG books *Your Story* and *Our World* cover Baltimore fairly in-depth, with locations, aspects, NPCs, and plot hooks.

### Chicago is the default setting,

But it's more covered in the novels than in the game, so although there's a lot of Chicago in the game manuals there's no proper setting bible like Baltimore gets.

### and you can find some good Actual Play type cities if you look.

For example, [the excellent Rick Neal](http://www.rickneal.ca/?page_id=842) has two articles about the process, first [using Winnipeg as a model](http://www.rickneal.ca/?page_id=14) and then talking about it more generally [here](http://www.rickneal.ca/?p=599) and [here](http://www.rickneal.ca/?p=603).

### But I *strongly* recommend that you use these only as examples, and have your group its own setting.

City creation is also a great introduction to FATE's ethos and mechanics. Nothing will work for your group quite like a setting that they make themselves. The process can be a great experience in group cohesion, and you'll wind up with players who are much more engaged in the setting, its people, and its problems. I cannot recommend this process and its results highly enough.

That said, *please* look at Baltimore and Mr. Neal's Winnipeg. They're great examples (especially when taken together) of how the process works.